# What does this mean 想索者 >> the subtitle said Diver but I want a correct translation for this term

Tags: meaning, words

I'm reading a JP web game and this is the prologue, 2 characters seems to be some kind of cadet in a facility under the ocean. They're talking about training to become a 想索者 (Diver), but I don't think this is a correct TL so I want someone give me opinions about this

Cadet 1: 戦いって、やっぱり怖いのかな、とか。(I heard that the battles are really scary right?)

Cadet2: それはまた気の早い話だね (Well that's too early to tell)

私たち候補生はしばらく訓練を積んで、その成績次第で正式な**想索者**に選抜される。だから、その心配はけっこう先の話だと思うよ. (We cadets will train for a while, and depending on our performance, we will be selected to become official "Diver". So I think that worry of yours is quite a long ways off.)
それまでに、心の準備とかしておけばいいんじゃないかな (In the meantime, I think you should prepare yourself mentally and stuff like that instead)

I think they will "dive" inside some kind of dream world to battles against monsters/nightmares? Can someone explain to me this term **想索者**

Comment: This appears to be a neologism

Comment: Yes, this is a coined word, and the translator has the liberty to decide its translation taking the whole story into consideration.

Answer (score 4):

They must have coined that term to sound like [捜索者]{そうさくしゃ}, which means a person who searches for something or someone, often a missing person. The first character of the neologism is also pronounced そう and it is used in such words as [想像]{そうぞう} (imagination) and [空想]{くうそう} (daydream). Though no such word as 想索 exists, when native speakers see those Chinese characters, we understand it as some act of searching that involves some mental activity. 想索者 is a person who does that, whatever it is.